# Best algorithm to highlight a list of given words in an HTML file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, algorithm

I have some HTML files, upon which I have no control. Thus I can't change their structure or markup.

For each of these HTML files, a list of words would be found based on another algorithm. These words should be highlighted in the text of HTML. For example if the HTML markup is:

```
<p>
Monkeys are going to die soon, if we don't stop killing them. 
So, we have to try hard to persuade hunters not to hunt monkeys. 
Monkeys are very intelligent, and they should survive. 
In fact, they deserve to survive.
</p>
```

and the list of the words is:

```
are, we, monkey
```

the result should be something like:

```
<p>
    <span class='highlight'>Monkeys</span> 
    <span class='highlight'>are</span> 
going to die soon, if 
    <span class='highlight'>we</span> 
don't stop killing them. 
So, 
    <span class='highlight'>we</span> 
have to try hard to persuade hunters 
not to hunt 
    <span class='highlight'>monkeys</span>
. They 
    <span class='highlight'>are</span> 
very intelligent, and they should survive. 
In fact, they deserve to survive.
</p>
```

The highlighting algorithm should:

1. be case-insensitive
2. be written in JavaScript (this happens inside browser) (jQuery is welcomed)
3. be fast (be applicable for the text of a given book with almost 800 pages)
4. not showing browser's famous "stop script" dialog
5. be applicable for dirty HTML files (like supporting invalid HTML markup, say for example unclosed

   elements) (some of these files are HTML export of MS Word, and I think you got what I mean by dirty!!!)
6. should preserve original HTML markup (no markup deletion, no markup change except wrapping intended words inside an element, no nesting change. HTML should look the same before and after edit except highlighted words)

What I've done till now:

1. I get the list of words in JavaScript in an array like `["are", "we", "monkey"]`
2. I try to select text nodes in the browser (which is faulty now)
3. I loop over each text node, and for each text node, I loop over each word in the list and try to find it and wrap it inside an element

Please note that you can watch it online [here](http://phis.ir/book-text/871) (username: demo@phis.ir, pass: demo). Also current script could be seen at the end of the page's source.

Comment: Really, @Amberlamps? Does this sound that I should pay ;). There are tons of algorithm questions on SO. Do they all pay ;):).

Comment: why don't you try regular expression ? & what do u mean by you have no control ?

Comment: Well, I actually use RegExp @Unspecified, and by having no control, I mean that I'm trying to create a plugin for browsers, or let users submit their HTML, or stuff like that.

Comment: To prevent the "stop script" message, I'd try to implement it in such a way that the final script will only work on the visible content.

Comment: Actually, I've worked many hours on it to get the current result. But I'm not satisfied with the outcome at all. It's not deterministic, doesn't support every HTML markup (dirty markup), takes near 20 seconds for large HTML files, and has many more drawbacks. That's why I asked it here. No good answer can be found on SO questions.

Comment: A little sidenote: Using JS to manipulate the DOM you will never have to worry about "dirty markup". By the time you'll get access to the DOM, the browser will have fixed the markup as it sees fit. The the DOM access will allways work on "valid markup", though the structure might not be what was originally intended.

Answer (score 4):

Concatenate your words with `|` into a string, and then interpret the string as a regex, and then substitute occurences with the full match surrounded by the highlight tags.

Comment: Good suggestion buddy. How about trying to find `a` letter? doesn't that match `<a>` tag too? Can you post a sample code please.

Comment: In that case rather than running it on the html, you need to walk the dom doing replacements only on the plain text nodes.

Answer (score 2):

The following regular expressions works for your example. Maybe you can pick it up from there:

```
"Monkeys are going to die soon, if we don't stop killing them. So, we have to try hard to persuade hunters not to hunt monkeys. Monkeys are very intelligent, and they should survive. In fact, they deserve to survive.".replace(/({we|are|monkey[s]?}*)([\s\.,])/gi, "<span class='highlight'>$1</span>$2")
```

Comment: So, do you propose that I have to create the pattern dynamically?

Comment: I think your problem is more complex than you think. Just going by your array of words is a very simple approach. It would find `monkey` but not `monkeys`. You did not say anything about that in your requirements.

Comment: yep, thanks for mentioning, but right now, it's not a requirement. However, you're right, it might be required later.

Comment: I guess that goes into the field of [NLP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_language_processing)

Comment: @SaeedNeamati: Indeed it does! And that is far from trivial!

Answer (score 2):

I found the given problem very interessting. Here is what I came up with:

- use some plugin (or write one yourself), so that we are able be be notified when an element comes into view
- parse that elements text-nodes and wrap each word into a span element using a unqiue css-class name derived from the word itself
- add the ability to add css-rules for these unqiue class names

sample: http://jsbin.com/welcome/44285/

---

The code is very hacky, and only testet in the newest Chrome, but it worked for me and surely can be build upon.

```
/**
 * Highlighter factory
 *
 * @return Object
 */
function highlighter() {
  var
    me = {},
    cssClassNames = {},
    cssClassNamesCount = 0,
    lastAddedRuleIndex,
    cbCount = 0,
    sheet;

  // add a stylesheet if none present
  if (document.styleSheets.length === 0) {
    sheet = document.createElement('style');
    $('head').append(sheet);
  }

  // get reference to the last stylesheet
  sheet = document.styleSheets.item(document.styleSheets.length - 1);

  /**
   * Returns a constant but unique css class name for the given word
   * 
   * @param String word
   * @return String
   */
  function getClassNameForWord(word) {
    var word = word.toLowerCase();
    return cssClassNames[word] = cssClassNames[word] || 'highlight-' + (cssClassNamesCount += 1);
  }

  /**
   * Highlights the given list of words by adding a new css rule to the list of active
   * css rules
   * 
   * @param Array words
   * @param String cssText
   * @return void
   */
  function highlight(words, cssText) {
    var
      i = 0,
      lim = words.length,
      classNames = [];

    // get the needed class names
    for (; i < lim; i += 1) {
      classNames.push('.' + getClassNameForWord(words[i]));
    }

    // remove the previous added rule
    if (lastAddedRuleIndex !== undefined) {
      sheet.deleteRule(lastAddedRuleIndex);
    }

    lastAddedRuleIndex = sheet.insertRule(classNames.join(', ') + ' { ' + cssText + ' }', sheet.cssRules.length);
  }

  /**
   * Calls the given function for each text node under the given parent element
   *
   * @param DomElement parentElement
   * @param Function onLoad
   * @param Function cb
   * @return void
   */
  function forEachTextNode(parentElement, onLoad, cb) {
    var i = parentElement.childNodes.length - 1, childNode;
    for (; i > -1; i -= 1) {
      childNode = parentElement.childNodes[i];
      if (childNode.nodeType === 3) {
        cbCount += 1;

        setTimeout(function (node) {
          return function () {
            cb(node);
            cbCount -= 1;
            if (cbCount === 0 && typeof onLoad === 'Function') {
              onLoad(me);
            }
          };
        }(childNode), 0);

      } else if (childNode.nodeType === 1) {
        forEachTextNode(childNode, cb);
      }
    }
  }

  /**
   * replace each text node by span elements wrapping each word
   *
   * @param DomElement contextNode
   * @param onLoad the parent element
   * @return void
   */
  function add(contextNode, onLoad) {
    forEachTextNode(contextNode, onLoad, function (textNode) {
      var
        doc = textNode.ownerDocument,
        frag = doc.createDocumentFragment(),
        words = textNode.nodeValue.split(/(\W)/g),
        i = 0,
        lim = words.length,
        span;

      for (; i < lim; i += 1) {
        if (/^\s*$/m.test(words[i])) {
          frag.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(words[i]));
        } else {
          span = doc.createElement('span');
          span.setAttribute('class', getClassNameForWord(words[i]));
          span.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(words[i]));
          frag.appendChild(span);
        }
      }

      textNode.parentNode.replaceChild(frag, textNode);
    });
  }

  // set public api and return created object
  me.highlight = highlight;
  me.add = add;

  return me
}

var h = highlighter();
h.highlight(['Lorem', 'magna', 'gubergren'], 'background: yellow;');

// on ready
$(function ($) {
  // using the in-view plugin (see the full code in the link above) here, to only
  // parse elements that are actual visible
  $('#content > *').one('inview', function (evt, visible) {
    if (visible) {
      h.add(this);
    }
  });

  $(window).scroll();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try a lib called [Linguigi](https://github.com/Prinzhorn/Linguigi) which I hacked together

```
var ling = new Linguigi();

ling.eachToken(/are|we|monkey/g, true, function(text) {
    return '<span class="highlight">' + text + '</span>';
});
```

Comment: Seems interesting. How about its performance? Does it work on large HTML files?

Comment: @SaeedNeamati try it. DOM manipulations is usually slow, but Linguigi takes the most unobtrusive approach. It would probably be faster to take the whole `innerHTML` as one big string.

Comment: I didn't. I'll check later when I'm at home.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jQuery, Try this.

```
$('* :not(:has(*))').html(function(i, v) {
  return v.replace(/searchString/g, '<span class="highlight">searchString</span>');    
});




$('* :not(:has(*))') will search for each node having no child elements and replace the html string in it with given string warapped in your HTML.
```

My quick and dirtier solution is based on the soultion in this blog:

http://wowmotty.blogspot.in/2011/05/jquery-findreplace-text-without.html

His solution works for a div selector and replaces just the text, mine tries to replace the innerHTML string.

Try this and tell mewhat all can be done. Seem interesting.

Comment: You will have to loop thru your array to take search Strings one at a time and put the code above in a function.

Comment: So, I have to run this function per each word in the given list. This means that for each word, the function should find **all** the text nodes in the browser, and run that function on it. Seems a little slow to me. Let me try.

Comment: best thing will be to use something other than DOM manipulation. Use something other than JS like a perl script and run it over the HTML files, search for regex instead of dom nodes.

Comment: you can find text nodes once and store them in an array. Then just loop thru the array every time for your words.